# i can not hide a blockTable?

Tags: table

I have a problem , i want to show a block table on a click but it does not work ,i wrapped the block table within a div (contains the onclick event)

```
 <div onclick="afficherTache(this)" style="display:none;">
```

but when i checked the rendered HTML code with firebug i realised that the content of the block table was not contained inside the div and consequently all the table elements are not hidden initially as expected . i have no idea why it does not works so any help will be appreciated
Here is the code :

```
<apex:column breakbefore="true" colspan="4" onmouseover="affiche(this);"><div id ="{!sr}aaaa" style="display:none;">
<apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1" id="lelock2">
<apex:repeat value="{!listPID}" var="key" >
<div style="font-size:130%;">{!key}
<div onclick="afficherTache(this)" style="display:none;">
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!listPID[key]}" var="item">
<apex:column >
<apex:facet name="header">Tache</apex:facet> 
<apex:outputtext Value="{!item.name}" ></apex:outputtext>
</apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</div>
</div>
</apex:repeat>                          
</apex:pageblocksection>
</div>
</apex:column>
```

ere is the firebug code html code rendered for the div that should hide the table elements ( nothing inside the div ???) :

```
<div style="display:none;" onclick="afficherTache(this)"></div>
```

Comment: Try `<apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="display:none;" onclick="afficherTache(this)">...</apex:outputPanel>` instead; this emits a `div` and may behave better in your page. Or simpler, put `style="display:none;" onclick="afficherTache(this)"` directly on the `apex:pageBlockTable`.